# MATLAB - apply multiple convolution masks to a single matrix

Tags: matlab, convolution

I need to convolve a matrix with many other matrices with few calls to convn.

for example: I have `size(MyMat)=[fm, fm ,1, bSize]` and `size(masks)=[s, s, maskNum]`

I want `res(:,:,k,:)` to be the product of convolving `masks(:,:,k)` with `MyMat`

`res(:,:,k,:)=convn(MyMat,masks(:,:,k));`

since the convolution takes up over 80% of the running time for my script and is called hundreds of thousands of times, I don't want to use a loop.

I'm looking for the fastest way to do this. basically, you could say I have `bSize` matrices, and I want to apply convolution masks `masks` to all of them with as few calls as possible to convolution.

The matrices are all small,non-sparse, fft-based convolution will probably slow it down (as a commentor here verified :) )

(The reason I have a 1 in the size of `MyMat` is because I actually have more elements in that dimension, but I compute the convolution for each element in **that** dimension in a loop)

The main goal is simply to eliminate the need for the following loop, or make it parallel with very little overhead, if possible:

```
for i=1:length
res(:,:,:,i)=convn(MyArray,convMask(:,:,i));
end
```

parallelizing for the GPU would be great if there's a way to do this with less overhead than the usual parfor

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "small"? 10-by-10-ish or 100-by-100-ish?

Comment: matrix sizes can be anywhere between 1x1x10x1000 to 9x9x20x1000, but the convolutions would be between matrices of size up to 9x9x1x1000 (and in the future maybe 21x21x1x1000). The convolutions will be applied with multiple masks, which will account for the 3rd dimension

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are preallocating the array `res` correctly? Without a simple demo of what your doing and an idea of the size of `fm`, `s`, etc., one can only make guesses to help you. If the sizes of your matrices are large enough you might look into [FFT-based convolution methods](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/11/03/the-conv-function-and-implementation-tradeoffs/) (there are some for `convn` [on the Matlab File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/index?term=convn+fft)). If the data is sparse (> 50% zeros), you could try converting this to matrix multiplication and use sparse data types. You could also try [`gpuArray/convn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/using-gpuarray.html) if you have [a decent one](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/gpudevice.html).

Comment: It's a lot of operations on small matrices. not sparse.
but the point is not how to make each convolution spereratly as fast as possible, but how to apply all convolution masks to the matrix as fast as possible - faster, if possible, than looping on the masks.
parallel looping is also fine, but it might not be worth it due to the overhead- which is why i'm looking for an alternative

Comment: I've edited my question and added some clarification. I don't want to use FFT because, as I understand, it is less accurate than normal convolution, and not as useful with relatively small matrices.

Comment: @user1999728: If the matrices are small (but what do you mean by "small"?), FFT-based convolution may not help. However, maybe an [FFT-based `convn` method](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24504-fft-based-convolution) would still be beneficial if applied over many small matrices.

Comment: by small I mean currently 9x9, at most i'll use 21x21 matrices (doubtful though)
I forgot to mention - Yes. I am preallocating `res`. anyway, As i've clarified by editing my original question, the problem is the amount of calls to the functions, which I'm trying to reduce by calling `convn` less times, or finding a way to do the multiple convolutions without a sequential loop. I will, however, explore FFT based convolution to see if I can benefit more from them. Thank you!

Comment: @user1999728: Doing a simple test, as implemented, the `convnfft` function I linked to above does not seem to have any benefit for large numbers of small matrices of the size you mentioned (in fact, it's slower until the matrices are just a bit larger than yours).

Comment: Thanks for trying. I read a bit about fftconv earlier, and I decided to go with parallelization of convn because I read that fftconv is meant for large matrices...